# Making an ajax call on a link click to update the link itself (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The application I'm working on has an updater page where clicking on a link will prompt a download of the latest version of the iOS app. However, when the updater page is opened from a webclip, the webclip may not have the latest version. My solution is to run an ajax query to retrieve the latest version.

Here is the query:

```
$('.download-link').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/updater",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result){
        }
    })
})
```

Here is the method in the controller:

```
def update
  @version = AppVersion.find_by(app_type: "AppType", is_active: true)
end
```

Here is the associated link in the updater.html.erb file:

```
<a class="download-link" href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<%= @version.link_to_stable_build %>">
```

I'm not super familiar with ajax and I'm not entirely sure where to go from here to actually make sure the method is called to update the link in the updater.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a view here. Just return a header only response with the URL in the Location header:

```
def update
  version = AppVersion.find_by(app_type: "AppType", is_active: true)
  url = "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=" + version.link_to_stable_build
  render head: :ok, 
         location: url
end
```

And then just update the DOM in your javascript handler:

```
// delegation makes this compatible with turbolinks
$(document).on('click', '.download-link', function(event) {
  let link = $(this);  
  // shorthand for $.ajax ....
  $.get("/updater", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    let uri = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location');
    link.attr('href', uri);
    // or if you want to promt a download 
    // window.location = uri;
  });
});
```